# `wiley-article.cls' not found

Tags: errors, document-classes, overleaf

I'm trying to submit a paper to Magnetic Resonance in Medicine (MRM) journal.

I downloaded the LaTeX template provided by Overleaf from here:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-magnetic-resonance-in-medicine-mrm/jnpvcyzrzdyj

In MRM submission website you have to upload the figures separated from the text and it only accepts the main document in `.tex` format. So I added the references manually using

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem
\end{thebibliography}
```

When I compile the `.tex` in TeXstudio it works fine. Then I tried to upload it in MRM website and I am getting the error

> ! LaTeX Error: File `wiley-article.cls' not
>   found.

Does anybody knows how to fix that?

I am using the `\documentclass[num-refs]{wiley-article}`

Comment: Why don't you ask the overleaf support as they are offering the template?

Comment: I already did but I haven't received a useful reply yet.  So I thought to write here in case someone else faced similar problem

Comment: I've added the `overleaf` tag, since resolving your query appears to depend on that source

Comment: Have you also uploaded wiley-article.cls along with your submission to the journal?

Comment: Where can I find the Wiley-article.cls?

Comment: your log-file should show you where it is on your system. And sorry I misunderstood your question, I thought you hadn't the class at all.

Comment: If you had been able to compile your manuscript with `\documentclass{wiley-article}` on Overleaf, then you must already have the `wiley-article.cls` in your Overleaf project: look in the file list panel. You can download a complete .zip of your Overleaf project, including wiley-article.cls, by clicking on the Overleaf menu icon above the file list panel and then on "Download - Source".

Comment: I uploaded the Wiley-article.cls as suggested and it worked. Thanks a lot.